# Like Ruby 'exec' but for Node.js?

Tags: ruby, node.js, process

I'm looking for a command like Ruby's kernel 'exec' but for Node.js. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you describe what you want to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the running process with the child process in and identical manner to Ruby's 'exec'.

Comment: For those of us familiar with Node but not Ruby, perhaps you could explain why Node's `child_process.exec` is not satisfactory.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I want to replace the running process with the child process. Write a quick ruby script to test this behavior, put only the following line: exec('node'). You'll notice that the ruby interpreter is now the node interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the advice of [@phs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580412/phs) and built a native Node.js module. A bit of details can be found [here](http://procbits.com/2011/12/04/node-js-exec-like-ruby-exec-and-writing-a-node-js-native-add-on-module/). Github source [here](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec).

You can use it like so:

`npm install kexec`

```
var kexec = require('kexec');
kexec("your_process with args here");
```

Comment: Trying to decide if I can afford the time to patch this for Windows support. (It's clearly possible, both Ruby's `exec()` and Python's `execv()` are cross-platform.)

Answer (score 5):

If you only care about posix platforms you could craft a small module in C and drop down to [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).

For some pointers on how you might do that, first realize that node is a framework that runs on top of [v8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/), and then take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/get_started.html) or perhaps [this](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html).

Comment: Awesome. Any tutorials on how I can do this?

Comment: @JPRichardson You're looking at getting dirty with v8 extensions.  I've updated the answer with a few links to get started.

Comment: Thanks, I gave you an upvote as I didn't think of this as an option previously.