# Is there a way to call an exec(2) function from a Node.js program?

Tags: unix, node.js, process

I want to replace my Node.js program with another one. Do I have to work around this by calling `child_process.spawn` and doing the right thing for all the events, or is there a way to call an `exec(2)` function directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like Ruby 'exec' but for Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362181/like-ruby-exec-but-for-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, looks like this is a duplicate of [Like Ruby 'exec' but for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362181/like-ruby-exec-but-for-node-js). (Can you mark questions as duplicates on Stack Overflow?

**Answer:** `npm install kexec`